# Mac OS Shell exec command with a pipe in it

Tags: macos, bash, shell

It might be a really dummy question but I'm banging my head against the wall here...

Why does this code :

```
#!/bin/bash -x    
cmd="launchctl list | grep -i \"twshows\""
echo $($cmd)
```

Produce this output :

```
% ./test.sh
+ cmd='launchctl list | grep -i "twshows"'
++ launchctl list '|' grep -i '"twshows"'
usage: launchctl list [-x] [label]
+ echo
```

Instead of simply executing the command. 
What is wrong with this pipe ? Is not well escaped ? 
I'm really desperate here, never encounter such thing on linux :/

I've searched a lot but been unable to find a satisfying answer.

thank you very much for any tips !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so I'm answering myself... I found out that when doing ths :

```
echo $(launchctl list | grep -i "aqua")
```

It works.

The main difference being the escaping technique. If you escape the whole command, like so :

```
echo $(" launchctl list | grep -i "aqua" ")
```

The command will not be found. 
If you put the command in a variable, the same will happend.
And finally, if you escape the double quotes for grep, it will not works either.

So the only solution is to NOT escape the command, seems strange to me but at leat.. it works !

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to do is use `eval` to evaluate the `$cmd` variable:

```
#!/bin/bash -x    
cmd="launchctl list | grep -i \"twshows\""
eval $cmd
```

#### Big Scary Warning

`eval` can be quite **evil** because it will evaluate whatever is in that variable. If that variable is initialized from user-supplied input, say `rm -rf \; echo 'gotcha!'` it will execute that with the same privileges as the shell you are running it under.

Comment: This is the debug of this script :  ` % ./test.sh                                                                                                         (03-31 19:43)
+ cmd='launchctl list | grep -i "twshows"'
+ eval launchctl list '|' grep -i '"twshows"'
++ launchctl list
++ grep -i twshows`

Comment: Sorry the code is all messed up. Could not find how to edit propely (a preview would be usefull :/). And so it does not work either as you can see...

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the command into a variable! Just execute it! What's wrong with :

```
#!/bin/bash
launchctl list | grep -i \"twshows\"
```

Comment: This one does not work as the command are launched separately. So grep does not have the input stream. And strangely enough, I don't see the output of launchctl list either... If I launch this command alone (without grepping), works like a charm.

Comment: Well that's what I got when executing your code.
If I launch "launchctl list" alone, works perfectly well. But anyway, the answer is not valid because I really need to be able to execute any command (it's an execute bash function). So simply launching the command won't work, it's my bad I did not precise it in my questions.
I had never notice this before, I had always programmed in shell for linux, never for mac.